# Google Play App Signing for Ionic 2 Apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-play, apk

I just wanted to upload a new Ionic 2 Android app to Google Play when Google asked me if I wanted to use Google App Signing. I liked the idea since it already had happened that I lost a certificate and was not able to update my app anymore.

But I can't find any help or tutorials on this anywhere. So my question is what steps I have to take to use Google App Signing for Ionic 2 Apps? Where do I get my Upload Certificate from?

All help I found was regarding Android Studio but I guess that does not help me with my Ionic 2 App.

In the help documents it says that the upload certificate is generated when enrolling Google App Signing but under App Signing in Google Play it does not give me the upload certificate.

Does any work have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I started a project from scratch and had to sign it as you always do and upload the manually signed apk after my listing was complete. After that I noticed both the app signing and upload key were available in the app signing section. Then future apps can then be signed with Google.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I will see if I can use auto signing in the future. I think that it's a very helpful feature.